# in html, window.onpopstate fires both on loading and on back arrow - how to know?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, popstate

on my page, I have a listener on `window.onpopstate`

I wish to trap the user's back arrow and run my own routine

but `window.onpopstate` fires when 1) the page is initially loaded, 2) is reloaded, as well as when 3) user presses the back arrow

I *could* create a state space flag and check it.  but more natural would be to determine from the event itself what's going on.

is there anything intrinsic way to determine whether the event was fired from loading or back button?  when I inspect the two events, they look pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `window.onpopstate` event is triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document, i.e. every time the active history entry changes.

It is fired when clicking on back button, on page load and also on page reload (Firefox doesn't emit this event on page load). So, the behavior you are seeing is intended.

And, for the back button, i guess there is no any way to detect the back-button-click using this event.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how I can get the context: load, reload, or backspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can compensate for popstate bugs in browsers. When someone uses my editor and hits the Backspace button sometimes that triggers navigation (this should not be a default but not everyone is qualified for their position) so I cancel it (yes, you can) and then fix the address bar with `history.go(1);`. I'm not posting dependency related code here as various people will need this for different contexts but it forms the basis of what you'll need.

```
window.onpopstate = function(e)
{
 if (id_('editor') && is_node_parent(document.activeElement,id_('editor')))
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  history.go(1);
 }
}
```